# Directive ngChange fires as many times as combobox options

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-change

I have a Countries dropdown, nothin' fancy.  My only oddball requirement is that I want to be able to pass in an OnChange function from my controller so the Directive can run it.  [Here is a Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/a50u2BzqwBKvQ1Nx1RGe?p=preview)

In the Plunker, I have this basic template:

```
<div>
    <label for="countryDirective">Country</label>
    <select id="countryDirective" ng-model="country" ng-Change="countryChanged()" ng-options="obj.value as obj.name for obj in countries">
        <option value="">Choose Your Country</option>
    </select>
    <span>{{country}}</span>
</div>
```

The only difference between the On-Page HTML and the Directive Template is that I added ng-Change onto the On-Page HTML.

One point of note is in my Directive, I am using `require: '^ngChange'`.

I don't know why it isn't documented very well, but it works wonders and gets around all of the problems posed by other questions relating to change event firing before the scope is updated and other change issues.

However, the price for this elegance is that my countryChanged() function is being fired x times, where x is the number of items in the drop-down.  I assume because items are being observed one at a time and so changes keep happening?

So my main question is: How do I keep this elegance, but make the ng-Change only fire once per change?

**Edit:** Turns out switching to select ngOptions instead of option ngRepeat fixes my issue with them not sync'ing, but not the main issue of why my ngChange is firing x times in the Directive.

Comment: Try to replace your `ng-repeat` inside your option tag for an `ng-options` inside your `select` tag. Not sure if it'll fix your n calls problem but it might, and it's the recommended way to do what you want.

Comment: That doesn't fix the issue, but it is more elegant.  Sometimes I don't jump into the `ngOptions` before I finish a select because I'm more comfortable with `ngRepeat`.  But I went ahead and took that step and updated my Plunkr.  Still, didn't stop the onChange method from firing multiple times times.  But it did fix my second question and keeps them in sync for some reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess the issue was setValue: '=ngChange'

I changed it to setValue: '&ngChange' and added ng-change="setValue()" to `<select/>`

Now its triggering only once when you change it (verify console log).

I have updated plunker https://plnkr.co/edit/xYi4uoNLeJVvKAoZhjbH?p=preview

Comment: Good Catch.  I hadn't seen this answer in the last hour, and came to the conclusion, but since you posted it first, I certainly give you points.  Thanks for answering!